# jquery UI-tabs positioning pop-up div near them

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

For my page, I am using j-query's ui-tabs to separate some elements. I am using .mouseover and .mouseout to pop-up a little help div and want it aligned near the mouse pointer.

unfortunately, positioning it using pageX/pageY is not working so I'm manually moving it back. There should be a way to find its position though right? Since I'm using tabs, do I have to calculate offset somewhere or something?

Here's how I'm using it:

```
$(".hashelp").mouseover(function(e){
        offsety = 5;
        offsetx = 5; //pop-up slightly below and right of the mouse.
        if($(this).attr("id")=="tablist")
        {
            offsety = -200;
            offsetx = -50;
        }
        else if($(this).parent().hasClass("ui-tabs-panel"))
        {
            console.log("pagex: "+e.pageX+" pagey: "+e.pageY+" helpx: "+helpx+" helpy: "+helpy);
            offsety = -200;
            offsetx = -15;
        }
        if(firsttime){
        $(this).find(".help").eq(0).css("top",(e.pageY+offsety));
        $(this).find(".help").eq(0).css("left",(e.pageX+offsetx));
        $(this).find(".help").eq(0).show();
        }

    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find(".help").eq(0).hide();
    });
```

Here's the html of the tabs:
I use $("#tabgroups").tabs() to create it.

```
<div id="tabgroups">
      <ul id="tablist" class="hashelp">
        <li><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
        <div class="help" style="display:none;">
        please choose the right tab
        </div>
     </ul>
   <div id="tab1">
    <ul id="common" class="hashelp">
      <li><button>commonchoice1<button></li>
    <div class="help" style="display:none;">
    Some help stuff
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please?

Comment: Probably can't get the position you want because the tabs don't have a `position:relative;` so it's taking the next nearest container, which I'd imagine to be the entire UL.

Comment: pageX and pageY are supposed to get the mouse position, then I set the div with position absolute

Comment: we need some html here, to help

Comment: I'm sorry, I added a stripped down version of the html for the tab-ui

Comment: <ul> tag can't have child <div> tag, only <li>

Comment: that still doesn't explain why the absolute positioning is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this after looking at where the divs where. Since they were nested, they were behaving badly, so I detached each div and appended them to the body element so they would get the correct x & y. Now it works beautifully.

```
var helppopup;
$(".hashelp").mouseover(function(e){
        offsety = 5;
        offsetx = 5;
            helppopup =  $(this).find(".help").eq(0);
        if(firsttime){
        $("body").append(helppopup.detach());
        helppopup.css("top",(e.pageY+offsety));
        helppopup.css("left",(e.pageX+offsetx));
        helppopup.show();
        }

    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).append(helppopup.detach())
        helppopup.hide();
    });
```